# Looking for a class in large dbml files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

Hi does someone know a quick way to find a class in large dbml files. We have a large data model and it takes a good 2-3 minutes to scroll and locate the required class. Zooming out makes it quite hard to see.

There has to be a better way than manually looking around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the dbml file, come into the properties tab and look for your class in controls dropdown list.